# Can I use AdSense with GitHub Pages?

Tags: github-pages, adsense

I'd like to add Google AdSense to my GitHub Pages website.

#### Problem:

AdSense scans the root page (`<user>.github.io`). But I can only edit a repository page (`<user>.github.io/<repo>`). So the root will always return `404`, making it non-eligible for AdSense.

#### Possible Solutions:

I can see 3 possible solutions:

1. Use my own domain. (I know that would work, but I don't want a domain for that)
2. Somehow edit my root Github page `<user>.github.io`
3. Setup AdSense to ignore my root and scan my sub-repo.

#### Question:

Is any of options 2 or 3 feasible? How?

Comment: This is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69122589/how-to-make-google-auto-ads-work-with-react-ssr-application/69154282, You could use DFP to serve ads in subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Your option 2 is definitely possible.

**Steps:**

1. Create a repository with the name: `<user>.github.io`
2. Enable GitHub Pages for that repository
3. Put whatever site content in that repository.
4. It's URL will be (assuming you enable https): `https://<user>.github.io`

As you already discovered, if GitHub Pages is enabled on a repository with any other name, the URL will be: `https://<user>.github.io/<repository>`. Those are basically project sites, whereas you are looking for a user site.